# How can I control what information is contained in one pixel of imagesc image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

For example, I plot the frequency-time dependence of an azimuthal angle of the Poynting vector `phi`. It is an array containing 5000x3000 elements. I make a color image using `imagesc(t, f, phi)`, which plots all of my 5000x3000 dots. But when I print this image I get a picture with a size of 900x1200 pixels.

How many elements of the array `phi` are in one pixel of the printed picture? Is some information deleted?

My code:

```
h1=figure(1,"visible","on"); 
imagesc(t, f, phi);
print(h1,"angle",'-dpng');
```

Comment: With 'print' do you mean on your screen or on paper (=to file)? On your screen the resolution is obviously limited to the amount of pixels on your screen, and [`print`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) has the ability to control the amount of pixels being printed to file.

Comment: I mean save to a file. For example, pic.png

Comment: The problem is how you are saving it. Shows us how, we might suggest something else

Comment: `print` saves what is shown in the screen, **not** the data. You may want to try `imwrite`